# Отчество от имени Франсуа

Tags: лексика, стилистика

Справочной службе русского языка Института лингвистических исследований РАН и Института русского языка имени В.В. Виноградова РАН задали вопрос: "Отправляем ребенка в школу. Обязательно нужно указать отчество. Отец — Франсуа".

Вопрос, думаю, интересный. Как быть в таких случаях? К сожалению, мне неизвестно, что ответила справочная служба. [Эсквайр.ру](https://esquire.ru/linguistic-investigation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По типу отчеств от имён с последней ударной а/я (от Лука, Илья, Илия), которая в отчестве утрачивается, можно такое предложить:

```
Лукич, Лукинична, Ильич Ильинична -> Франсуич Франсуинична
```

Меньше оснований ориентироваться на такой известный прецедент, где гласная сохраняется: (от Мацуо) Мацуович Мацуовна (Франсуа/о/вич, Франсуа/о/вна)

Comment: Александр, а встречаются ли такие отчества на практике? Первые мне известны, а вот такие, как Мацуович Мацуовна (от Мацуо)(Франсуа/о/вич, Франсуа/о/вна) встречать не приходилось.

Comment: Ирина Мацуовна Хакамада, российский политик (отец - японец).

Comment: А от Франсуа и подобных имен вам доводилось встречать фамилии?

Comment: Не надо придумывать "основания". Надо просто ориентироваться на общие свойства русского языка.

Comment: @Серж Нет, только сейчас, после того как придумал, поиском нашёл обрывок из форума - по первому варианту (всего два результата). https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=RwL8VciyK8mcsgHo9LXIAg#newwindow=1&q=%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0

Answer (score 4):

[Франсуаевич, Франсуаевна - Склонение имён и отчеств | udarenieru.ru](http://udarenieru.ru/index.php?fio=on&fio_word=%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

Шаблон берите по Абдулла, Джума и т.д.

Кузьма, Фома - здесь не проходит, имена славянского происхождения, их парадигма не применима к французским.

Answer (score 3):

Отчество получается если к корню имени отца добавить -ович (-овна) или -ич (-ична). Соответственно, если ограничиться этим, то отчество должно быть *Франсуаович, Франсуаевич* или *Франсуаич*. Эти варианты возможны, но стечение трёх гласных делает их неудобными в произношении.

Другой вариант, сократить это стечение гласных *Франсуович*, и *Франсуич*. Второй вариант лучше отмести в виду неблагозвучия, а первый вполне возможен.

Третий вариант, по аналогии с Яков-Яковлевич добавить вставку для удобства произношения, в данном случае напрашивается "з" - *Франсуазович*.

И последний вариант обрусить (точнее онемечить) имя отца и образовывать отчество от Франц. Тогда *Францевич* получается легко, но отчество сильно искажается

Таким образом, я бы остаовился на двух вариантах *Франсуович-Франсуовна* и "Франсуазович-Франсуазовна", хотя *Франсуаевич-Франсуаевна* тоже возможна.

P.S. С точки зрения закона отчество у ребёнка то, что записано в свидетельстве о рождении. Если у него в документах нет отчества, то в графе отчество просто ставится прочерк. Из известных граждан РФ отчества нет, например, у Тинатин Канделаки.

Comment: Марк, на мой взгляд, в таких случаях лучше не указывать отечество, как например у Тины Канделаки. Отчество от имени Франсуа как-то слух режет.

Answer (score 1):

Образец решения (возможно, замена Франсуа - Франц?):

Граф Карл Францевич Сен-При (Арман Шарль Эммануэль Гиньяр, граф де Сен-При; Armand-Charles-Emmanuel de Guignard, comte de Saint-Priest; 8 сентября 1782 — 1863) — из французских дворян, херсонский и подольский губернатор.

Comment: А это не разные имена? Кстати, служб ответила так: ""К именам, оканчивающимся на ударные гласные -а, -я, -е, -э, -и, -ы, -о, -ё, -у, -ю добавляется -евич, -евна при этом конечный гласный сохраняется. Исключение: русские имена Илья, Лука, Кузьма, Фома".

Видать, по правилу Франсуаевич.

Впрочем, в правилах есть примечание, что по согласованию с родителями можно дать отчество, которое образовано не по правилу, но уже принято в обществе. Типа Шотович более распространено, чем Шотаевич (от имени Шота)."

Comment: В Википедии приводится соответствие немецкого "Франца" именно "Франсуа" (они совпадают по значению, в отличие от другого французского Франк*). В данном примере могло сказаться немецкое влияние на имена: в Россию он попал при Екатерине (1791) + мать его была немка. Но видимо, существуют и более "строгие" случаи трансформации французских имён, поскольку немецкий вариант лучше адаптируется к русским языковым потребностям - отчества Францевич или Карлович (но не Шарлевич) интуитивно припоминаются.* http://mennames.ru/francuzskie-muzhskie-imena/

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб не преодолевать барьер череды гласных, резонно отказаться от **А** и заменить **У** на родственную ей **О**: Франсович (Франсовна).